# Как получить гладкие кривые в Android при рисовании по касанию?

Tags: android, touch-event

Обработчик `onTouchEvent` в `ACTION_MOVE` рисует прямую линию к `event.getX()`, `event.getY()`. В итоге при рисовании пальцем по экрану линия получается рубленой. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `event.getX()`, `event.getY()` нужно использовать `event.getHistoricalX()`, `event.getHistoricalY()`, в цикле по `i` пробегая по всем точкам.